adding dependency in intellij not working
adding dependency in intellij
I'm encountering an issue in IntelliJ where I can't seem to add new dependencies to my pom.xml file directly. Whenever I try to search for dependencies, including Querydsl or others, IntelliJ reports "no dependencies found." Is there a way to resolve this and successfully add dependencies through IntelliJ without manually copying and pasting from the Maven repository? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
intellij ultimate version
JDK 17 Oracle OpenJDK
expected to be able to search for and add dependencies seamlessly within IntelliJ without resorting to manual copying and pasting from the Maven repository. However, despite attempting to add dependencies through the IDE, I couldn't find any available dependencies.I am aware that needs internet connectivity so that it can download the dependency.But still no Dependency is found in my intellij

Can you check if you have Package Search Plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12507-package-search) installed?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
